# Wordpress Site SLOW to Load

Tags: mysql, css, wordpress

I just uploaded a Wordpress site from my local machine to a Bluehost shared server. Ran fine locally, but now it is loading very slowly (107 seconds for home page). Bluehost tech support ran GTMetrix site analyzer and came back with "it's the CSS in your theme". They say nothing is wrong with the server.

I definitely need to clean up my CSS, but I didn't think it could have such a large impact on load times. Am I wrong?

Comment: It's not the CSS. Chrome tells me that your main HTML document took 50 seconds to load completely. It's something in your code, but without more information it's impossible to say what. Perhaps you are trying to connect to some server (database?) that cannot be connected to from your host, and the delay is due to the connection finally timing out.

Comment: @Jon: Same for me in Firefox.

Comment: @animuson: I'm pretty much convinced that's exactly what it is. Expanded the comment into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the resource load times with Chrome's developer tools makes it immediately clear that it's your main document that is responsible for the delay; not the CSS, not anything else.

Therefore we have to assume it's something in your own code that causes the delay. Since it worked fine when run locally, the most likely scenario is that your code is trying to connect to some server (perhaps a database?) that it cannot connect to, and the delay is due to the connection finally timing out.

Recommendation: double check the places where you make connections to any external resource, and especially the credentials used when you do so. Is your host authorized to make these connections the same as your local development machine is? If you are connecting by IP, are those IPs accessible from your host?

Comment: It was an image in one of the posts pointing to my local server. Thanks for diagnosing!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is loading

```
http://ad.doubleclick.net/adi/N5192.395082.LOT18.COM/B5529584;sz=300x250;ord=[timestamp]?
```

which is probably a script?

That takes 59 seconds for me. The rest is fast.

From the Chrome dev tools (Network tab): http://screencast.com/t/8DdtXeEv

The solution: turn off your ads.

Comment: That loads (or actually, fails to load) instantaneously for me. Your screenshot itself depicts what my comment above says: it's the main document that delays loading. Also, DoubleClick (of all people) taking 1 minute to load is ridiculous.

Comment: Maybe I'm pointing to something on my local machine and that's the timeout it's waiting on. I'll poke around.

Comment: @chris_mac, looking at my Safari console, it took over 55 seconds just to load this one file...  `/lot18/wp-includes/js/l10n.js`.  Then after disabling JavaScript, it took over 55 seconds to load the CSS, which loaded fast before.  This is really weird.

Comment: Then after another refresh, CSS loads fast and the main document takes 59 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use quick cache plugin which will speed up you site without compromise.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/quick-cache/